# Yii - How to validate a textfield for integers only

Tags: php, yii, yii-events

The below model extends CFormModel and I need to mention rules to it such that the attributes allow only integers.

```
class SearchForm extends CFormModel {

    public $min_size;
    public $max_size;

    /**
     * Declares the validation rules.
     * The rules state that username and password are required,
     * and password needs to be authenticated.
     */
    public function rules() {
array('min_size, max_size', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),

        );
    }
```

The textfield is created using -

```
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'min_size', array('placeholder' => 'Min Sqft', 'style'=>'width:100px')); ?>
```

But, the above validation is not working. How can I validate the text field to allow integers only. Is there anyway I can do validation

Comment: Post the controller code. Are you calling validate() ?

Comment: try to add type validator also to these fields. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CTypeValidator

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
public function rules(){
return array(
    array('min_size, max_size', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true));}
```

Comment: check out _form.php for $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
 'id'=>'member-form',
 'enableAjaxValidation'=>true, //make this true
));

Comment: <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); //uncomment this code in form.php ?>

Comment: also checkout in controller

Answer (score 2):

use like in v2

```
[['mobile'], 'integer'],
[['mobile'], 'string', 'min' => 10, 'max' => 10],
```

Comment: Try to detail why this would work. Given as is it won't help anyone understand why/how your answer would solve OP problem.